# Encoding in docusaurus

Tags: utf-8, docusaurus

I am using in project German alphabet, so I need to use ü, ä, ö. But instead of this, when I run the server, I got �. How can I fix it?

I thought that I need to add to my static index.html meta data charset utf-8, but it was already there and it didn't work.

Comment: Is your project in `utf-8` as well? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe is your web browser the problem? Because I also use "special characters" like "ã" and it works like a charm. Note: I just tested ü, ä, ö and it printted correctly.

Comment: Like @JosefZ said, check if your **markdown files** are in `utf-8`.

Comment: @JosefZ I create the MDX files via java. And when I do that in ide(Intellij) it creates UTF-8 mdx files, but when I do that via jar file it creates ANSI mdx files

Comment: found the problem, I just needed to create mdx files in java with utf8‍♂️